# 'Aw snap!' - How does Chrome use memory? My angular app keeps crashing

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

This is a general question I am trying to understand. I have an application that keeps running into out of memory issue. I've profiled the app extensively for memory leak issues with the dev-tools performance and memory tabs and memory usage is pretty consistent. My conclusion is that my app itself was taking up a lot of memory and causing it to crash.

Why this happens? My app has a functionality in which a user can open several child windows to run an certain operation concurrently for different items. So every time I open a new child window, the memory increases until that point where there is no more memory available and it crashes. 
However, the one things that I have not been able to understand is, at what point does Chrome decide that it cannot allocate more memory to my app. I noticed, that consistently the app crashed whenever I hit around 3,000,000K (around 3GB). My machine has 32GB RAM.

1. Am I right in thinking that in theory, if I have no other programs running on
   my system, Chrome should have the entire RAM available for it to
   keep using (minus the memory the OS and other essential processes
   need)?
2. Is there such a concept that the OS only allocates so much memory to
   a certain process (the browser in my case)?
3. Is there a concept that Chrome only allows so much memory for any single app?

I've Googled a lot looking for an answer and did not find anything that helped me understand why my app was not getting more memory if it needs it even though (assuming) it was available.

I have an AngularJS (1.6) app.

Comment: If you're running the 32bit version of Chrome you may be hitting the memory address limit. You can check which process is running by navigating to chrome://chrome

Comment: I'm running the 64bit version - Version 64.0.3282.168 (Official Build) (64-bit)
But thanks for pointing me in the right direction - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=416284

Comment: Have you looked into the `--max_old_space_size` flag for V8?

Comment: I am right now. Thanks!

Comment: @yazz how to you fix that. Can you share it here..